# Calculate the distance of object from perspective drawing

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, image-processing

[image: scenery]

Hello!
I would like to know if there is any way to calculate a distance based of this single point perspective drawing of a 17th century theatrical scenery :

We have this elements:

The real-life size of the object ABCD is (**AB** : $125$ cm ; **BD** : $75$ cm )

In the picture, the size of the object at the foreground is (**AB** : $2.5$ cm ; **BD** : $1.5$ cm)

In the picture, the size of the same object in the background is (**A'B'** : $1.16$ cm ; **B'D'** : $0.7$ cm)

The eye level is about $159$ cm.

The angle of the receding lines is $40^\circ$

Is it possible to evaluate the distance $d$ between the two objects in real life?

Thank you!